# Cluster overlapping circles?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to cluster(group) every circle that's uninterrupted overlapping (connected) to each other how could I do that? *(preferably in a pretty efficient way)*.

*(I have messed around trying to write some recursive functions but haven't gotten anything to work.)*

I have created a VS project to visualize the problem.

**[Download here:](http://www.patan77.com/download/clusterCircles.zip)**

**Generates Random circles.**
[image]

**How the clustering currently works:**
*(its only looks at what circle is overlapping that specific circle not all that is connected)*
[image]

**How it should look if its working** 
*(separate clusters for all connecting circles)*
[image]

**CODE: (C#)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

// Cluster overlapping circles
// Patrik Fröhler
// www.patan77.com
// 2017-08-14

namespace circleGroup
{
    struct circle // the circle "object"
    {
        public float[] pos;
        public int radius;
        public Color color;
        public int id;
        public float x
        {
            get { return pos[0]; }
            set { pos[0] = value; }
        }
        public float y
        {
            get { return pos[1]; }
            set { pos[1] = value; }
        }
    }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DB _DB = new DB(); // "Global Database"

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private static circle createCircle(float _x = 0, float _y = 0, int _radius = 1, Color? _color = null, int _id = -1) // creates a circle
        {
            circle tmpCircle = new circle() { pos = new float[2], x = _x, y = _y, radius = _radius, id = _id };
            tmpCircle.color = _color ?? Color.Black;
            return (tmpCircle);
        }

        private circle[] genRngCircles(int _n) // generates an array of random circles
        {
            Random rng = new Random();
            circle tmpC;
            circle[] tmpCarr = new circle[_n];
            for (int i = 0; i < _n; i++)
            {
                tmpC = createCircle();
                tmpC.radius = rng.Next(10, 75);
                tmpC.x = rng.Next(tmpC.radius, (512 - tmpC.radius));
                tmpC.y = rng.Next(tmpC.radius, (512 - tmpC.radius));
                tmpC.color = Color.FromArgb(127, rng.Next(0, 255), rng.Next(0, 255), rng.Next(0, 255));
                tmpC.id = i;
                tmpCarr[i] = tmpC;

            }
            return tmpCarr;
        }

        private void drawCircle(circle _circle, Graphics _g) // draws one circle
        {
            SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(_circle.color);
            _g.FillEllipse(sb, (_circle.x - _circle.radius), (_circle.y - _circle.radius), (_circle.radius * 2), (_circle.radius * 2));
            sb.Dispose();
        }

        private void drawString(float[] _pos, string _text, Graphics _g) // draws text
        {
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
            sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            Font font = new Font("Arial", 12);
            SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            float x = _pos[0];
            float y = _pos[1];
            _g.DrawString(_text, font, sb, x, y, sf);
            font.Dispose();
            sb.Dispose();
        }

        private void drawCircleArr(circle[] _circleArr, Graphics _g)// draws an array of circles
        {
            _g.Clear(panel1.BackColor);
            for (int i = 0; i < _circleArr.Length; i++)
            {
                drawCircle(_circleArr[i], _g);
                drawString(_circleArr[i].pos, _circleArr[i].id.ToString(), _g);
            }
        }

        static double mDistance<T>(T[] _p0, T[] _p1) // gets euclidean distance between two points of arbitrary numbers of dimensions
        {
            double[] p0 = new double[] { Convert.ToDouble(_p0[0]), Convert.ToDouble(_p0[1]) };
            double[] p1 = new double[] { Convert.ToDouble(_p1[0]), Convert.ToDouble(_p1[1]) };
            double tmp = 0;
            double tmpTotal = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < _p0.Length; i++)
            {
                tmp = (p0[i] - p1[i]);
                tmpTotal += (tmp * tmp);
            }
            double output = Math.Sqrt(tmpTotal);
            return (output);
        }

        private bool overlap(circle _c0, circle _c1) // checks if two circles overlap
        {
            double dis = mDistance(_c0.pos, _c1.pos);
            if (dis <= (_c0.radius + _c1.radius))
            {
                return (true);
            }
            return (false);
        }

        private Color avgColor(List<circle> _colorArr) // averages mutiple colors togehter
        {
            float ia = 0;
            float ir = 0;
            float ig = 0;
            float ib = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < _colorArr.Count; i++)
            {
                ia += _colorArr[i].color.A;
                ir += _colorArr[i].color.R;
                ig += _colorArr[i].color.G;
                ib += _colorArr[i].color.B;
            }
            byte a = Convert.ToByte(Math.Round(ia / _colorArr.Count));
            byte r = Convert.ToByte(Math.Round(ir / _colorArr.Count));
            byte g = Convert.ToByte(Math.Round(ig / _colorArr.Count));
            byte b = Convert.ToByte(Math.Round(ib / _colorArr.Count));

            return (Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b));
        }

        private void treeView(List<circle>[] _circleLArr) // Create Treeview
        {
            treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < _circleLArr.Length; i++)
            {
                treeView1.Nodes.Add(i.ToString());
                for (int j = 0; j < _circleLArr[i].Count; j++)
                {
                    treeView1.Nodes[i].Nodes.Add(_circleLArr[i][j].id.ToString());
                }
            }
            treeView1.ExpandAll();
        }

        private void drawCircleClusters(List<circle>[] _circleLArr, Graphics _g) // draws the circle clusters
        {
            _g.Clear(panel1.BackColor);
            circle tmpC;
            Color tmpColor;
            for (int i = 0; i < _circleLArr.Length; i++)
            {
                tmpColor = avgColor(_circleLArr[i]);
                for (int j = 0; j < _circleLArr[i].Count; j++)
                {
                    tmpC = _circleLArr[i][j];
                    tmpC.color = tmpColor;
                    drawCircle(tmpC, _g);
                    drawString(_circleLArr[i][j].pos, _circleLArr[i][j].id.ToString(), _g);
                }
            }
        }

        //----------------------------------------------------

        private List<circle>[] simpleOverlap(circle[] _circleArr) // test what circles overlaps 
        {
            List<circle>[] tmpLArr = new List<circle>[_circleArr.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < (_circleArr.Length); i++)
            {
                tmpLArr[i] = new List<circle>();
                for (int j = 0; j < (_circleArr.Length); j++)
                {
                    if (overlap(_circleArr[i], _circleArr[j]))
                    {
                        tmpLArr[i].Add(_circleArr[j]);
                    }
                }

            }
            return (tmpLArr);
        }

        /*
        private circle[] recurOverlap(circle[] _circleArr) // recursive overlap test(not done/working)
        {
            List<circle> overlapArr = new List<circle>();
            List<circle> dontOverlapArr = new List<circle>();
            bool loop = true;
            int n = 0;
            while (loop)
            {
                if (overlap(_circleArr[0], _circleArr[n]))
                {
                    overlapArr.Add(_circleArr[n]);
                    dontOverlapArr.Insert(0, _circleArr[n]);
                    circle[] dontArr = dontOverlapArr.ToArray();
                    recurOverlap(dontArr);
                }
                else
                {
                    dontOverlapArr.Add(_circleArr[n]);
                }
                n++;
                if (n >= _circleArr.Length)
                {
                    loop = false;
                }
            }
            if(_circleArr.Length <= 1)
            {
                return _circleArr;
            }
            else{
                return overlapArr.ToArray();
            } 
        }

        private List<circle>[] clusterBrecur(circle[] _circleArr)
        {
            List<circle>[] tmpLArr = new List<circle>[_circleArr.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < (_circleArr.Length); i++)
            {
                tmpLArr[i] = new List<circle>();
                recurOverlap(_circleArr);
            }
            return (tmpLArr);
        }*/


        private void run() // Run function
        {
            treeView1.Nodes.Clear(); // clear tree view
            _DB.g = panel1.CreateGraphics();// Create Panel Graphics to draw on
            _DB.circleArr = genRngCircles(10); // Creates an array with random circles
            drawCircleArr(_DB.circleArr, _DB.g); // Draws the random circles
            clusterAbtn.Enabled = true; // enables the cluster button
        }

        private void clusterA() // clusterA function
        {
            _DB.circleClusters = simpleOverlap(_DB.circleArr); // runs cluster algorithm test A
            treeView(_DB.circleClusters); // Creates the treeview
            drawCircleClusters(_DB.circleClusters, _DB.g); // draws the circle clusters
        }

        private void clusterB()
        {

        }

        private void clusterA_rClick()
        {
            drawCircleArr(_DB.circleArr, _DB.g); // Draws the random circles
        }

        private void runBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // run button click
        {
            run();
        }

        private void clusterAbtn_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
        {
            switch (e.Button)
            {
                case MouseButtons.Left:
                    clusterA();
                    break;
                case MouseButtons.Right:
                    clusterA_rClick();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void clusterBbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // clusterB button click
        {
            clusterB();
        }
    }

    class DB // "Database"
    {
        public Graphics g;
        public circle[] circleArr;
        public List<circle>[] circleClusters;
    }
}
```

The current "overlap function"

```
    private List<circle>[] simpleOverlap(circle[] _circleArr) // test what circles overlaps 
    {
        List<circle>[] tmpLArr = new List<circle>[_circleArr.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < (_circleArr.Length); i++)
        {
            tmpLArr[i] = new List<circle>();
            for (int j = 0; j < (_circleArr.Length); j++)
            {
                if (overlap(_circleArr[i], _circleArr[j]))
                {
                    tmpLArr[i].Add(_circleArr[j]);
                }
            }

        }
        return (tmpLArr);
    }
```

Comment: A bit unrelated, but be aware that [mutable structs are quite troublesome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/441309/2557263)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made following change to your code. Looks like working

```
    private List<circle>[] simpleOverlap(circle[] _circleArr) // test what circles overlaps 
    {
        List<List<circle>> list = new List<List<circle>>();

        //List<circle>[] tmpLArr = new List<circle>[_circleArr.Length];
        //for (int i = 0; i < (_circleArr.Length); i++)
        foreach (circle circle in _circleArr)
        {
            List<circle> cluster = null;
            //tmpLArr[i] = new List<circle>();
            //for (int j = 0; j < (_circleArr.Length); j++)
            //{
            //    if (overlap(_circleArr[i], _circleArr[j]))
            //    {
            //        tmpLArr[i].Add(_circleArr[j]);
            //    }
            //}
            foreach(List<circle> cluster2 in list)
            {
                foreach (circle circle2 in cluster2)
                {
                    if (overlap(circle, circle2))
                    {
                        cluster = cluster2;
                        goto label_001;
                    }
                }
            }
            label_001:
            if (cluster == null)
            {
                cluster = new List<circle>();
                list.Add(cluster);
            }
            cluster.Add(circle);
        }

        bool flag = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i += (flag ? 1 : 0))
        {
            flag = true;
            List<circle> cluster = list[i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j < list.Count; j++)
            {
                List<circle> cluster2 = list[j];
                if (Intersects(cluster, cluster2))
                {
                    cluster.AddRange(cluster2);
                    list.Remove(cluster2);
                    j--;
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return list.ToArray();
        //return (tmpLArr);
    }

    bool Intersects(List<circle> cluster1, List<circle> cluster2)
    {
        foreach (circle circle1 in cluster1)
        {
            foreach (circle circle2 in cluster2)
            {
                if (overlap(circle1, circle2))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I had to add 1 more method `bool Intersects(List<circle> cluster1, List<circle> cluster2)`. See if it helps.

Comment: thx, that works exactly as it should,"(flag ? 1 : 0)" is pretty clever also I did not know about "goto".

Answer (score 0):

I believe the function you are looking for is intersection. I have attached an article by Mike K which I believe will give you an idea of how to approach this in your own code.

[C# circles intersections](https://kociumbas.wordpress.com/2016/04/03/c-circles-intersections/)

Comment: I don't think that the problem is the intersection as the intersections are detected correctly. The problem seems to be the correct clustering. As seen in figure 1, circle "8" appears in two different clusters which must not happen, instead, the clusters should be joined, but that doesn't happen.